# Could not connect Error: Error during negotiation request

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr

My code should create chat communication between angular 8 asp.net web api 2 and signalR 2
**Server**
*hub*

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public  string Send(string data="hello")
    {           
       return Clients.All.SendAsync(data);
    }
  }
```

*startUp*

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
```

**angular client**

[image: angular code]
I got the error:

> Error during negotiation request

Comment: Thank you very much Dima Kozhevin for the effort  in editing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure it like this:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
   {
       map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
       var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
       map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
   });
}
```

```cs
[HubName("ChatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public  string Send(string data="hello")
    {           
       return Clients.All.SendAsync(data);
    }
}
```

```js
//jQuery
declare var $: any;

//server configuration
export let CONFIGURATION = {
    baseUrls: {
        server: 'https://localhost:51962'
    },
}
```

```js
private proxy: any;
private proxyName: string = 'ChatHub'; //defined in the hub
```

```js
private configureConnection() {

        // create hub connection  
        this.connection = $.hubConnection(CONFIGURATION.baseUrls.server);

        // create new proxy as name already given in top  
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);
    }
```

```js
// check in the browser console for either signalr connected or not  
    private startConnection(): void {
        this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
            console.log('Now connected ' + data.transport.name + ', connection ID= ' + data.id);
            this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
            this.connectionExists = true;

        }).fail((error: any) => {
            console.log('Could not connect ' + error);
            this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your offer but unfortunately it did not work,Because of the same error.
  Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: It did not work either
,Is it possible that it is because of the fact that client side written in angular 8?

Comment: It can be that you are missing jQuery on the angular side.

Comment: and Install :
`npm install — save @types/jquery
npm install — save @types/signalr`
also added scripts to angular-cli.json
“apps”: [{
 “scripts”: [
 “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js”,
 “../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js”
 ],
}]`